# Is there functionality to generate a random character in NSIS

Tags: random, char, nsis

I need to generate a random character during an NSIS installer script multiple times.
Is there a pre-defined function or is it even possible?
If yes: How?

Comment: Do you need it at compile time or run time?

Comment: I need it during the setup, meaning during runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no predefined function but the wiki has plugins and basic (non-crypto) pure NSIS random functions to choose from:

- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Rnd
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Random
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Pwgen_plug-in
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsRandom_plug-in
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Generate_a_random_number